# Use compareTo for year,month and day.. Java

Tags: java, date-comparison

I wanna sort the dates out on the screen but the thing is, when I use `compareTo` method, I can only use it with one of the Date attributes: Year, month or day.. not all of them. This is a custom class, not `java.util.Date` class.

I am required to sort it out on the screen using `compareTo` method.

This is what I have done.

```
public int compareTo(Date date) {
    if(getYear()-date.getYear()>0 && getMonth()-date.getMonth()>0){

        return 1;
    }
    if(getYear()-date.getYear()<0 && getMonth()-date.getMonth()<0 ){

        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with [`Date#compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date))?

Comment: Is this `java.util.Date` ? If so, it is already comparable

Comment: @khelwood no its user defined

Comment: How about `Comparator.comparing(Date::getYear).thenComparing(Date::getMonth).thenComparing(Date::getDay)`

Comment: @thefeels Post clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only compare the months if the years are equal. Similarly, you should only compare the days if the months are equal.

```
public int compareTo(Date date) {
    if(getYear() == date.getYear()) {
        if (getMonth() == date.getMonth()) {
            return getDay() - date.getDay ();
        } else {
            return getMonth() - date.getMonth ();
        }
    } else {
        return getYear() - date.getYear();
    }
}
```

Note that if for a given property the values of the two Dates are not equal, you can return the difference of those values instead of checking if it's positive or negative and then returning 1 or -1. `compareTo` is not required to return 1, 0 or -1. It can return any int value.

Comment: The method getYear() from the type Date is deprecated

Comment: @Crimean.us The author clarified that `Date` refers to a custom class, not `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 alleviates some of the boilerplate for sorting by particular fields with [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-).

```
dateList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Date::getYear)
                  .thenComparing(Date::getMonth)
                  .thenComparing(Date::getDay));
```

Comment: The method getYear() from the type Date is deprecated

Comment: @Crimean.us It's not `java.util.Date` . It's a custom Date class written by the OP. If it was `java.util.Date` it would already be comparable.